# Only show one content at the time (using {{each}} on HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars `{{each}}` to display the content.

Each content displays its data inside a div-box, so multiple content are displayed vertically, like:

```
  ______
 |      |
 |      |
 |______|
  ______
 |      |
 |      |
 |______|

//.. and so on
```

Instead, I would like to display one content at the time, and be able to change to the next content with a help of a button.

There's a button at the bottom-right corner which dosn't do anything for the moment.

```
  ______
 |      |
 |      |
 |___[>]| //click on the button, and the next content will display
```

---

HTML/Handlebar code:

```
 {{#each family}}
   <div class="content-wrapper">                  
    <h1>{{surName}}</h1>             

    {{#each member}}                
       <h2>{{firstName}}</h2>         
    {{/each}}      
    <button id="btn-next" type="submit">Next</button>
   </div>      
 {{/each}}
```

Is there any good way to achieve this?

Comment: handlerbar is logic-less : If you prevent logic in templates by design (like mustache does)
put the logic elsewhere, so your templates will end up uncluttered.

Comment: @M.Gara I see, can you put me in right direction how to "put the logic elsewhere"? Just started to learn node.js etc. Also, could pagination (showing one page at the time) be a solution or is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to put the logic in the javascript. Eg: store the current member on the family obj.

But handlebars does have if statements, so you could do something like this snippet:

```js
var context = {
  surName: 'last',
  selectedIdx: 0, // zero based index of selected family member
  member: null, // selected family member for handlebars
  members: [
    { firstName: 'first1', surName: 'last' },
    { firstName: 'first2', surName: 'last' },
    { firstName: 'first3', surName: 'last' },
  ],
};
render();

function render() {
  // set selected member for handlebars
  context.member = context.members[context.selectedIdx]

  var source = document.getElementById("fam-template").innerHTML;
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  document.getElementById("fam").innerHTML = template(context);

  // bind to click event of button added above
  // this needs to be done each time the next button is clicked
  // since the button is inside the handlebars template
  $("#btn-next").click(handleClick);
}

function handleClick() {
 // move to next family member
 context.selectedIdx++;
 // wrap around
 if (context.selectedIdx >= context.members.length) {
  context.selectedIdx = 0;
 }
 // re-render
 render();
}
```

```html
<script id="fam-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="content-wrapper">                  
    <h1>{{surName}}</h1>             
              
    <h2>{{member.firstName}}</h2>    
    <button id="btn-next" type="submit">Next</button>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="fam"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The snippet still show same values when you press 'next'-button

Comment: The button doesn't do anything. The snippet is just to show that you can have if statements.

Comment: I'm aware of if-statement, but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: I answered the question for showing one at a time. Are you now asking how to make the button change which one is showing?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using handlebars instead of say, react or angular? Handlebars is more of a render it once kind of library. There are much better libraries for rendering dynamic content.

Comment: I haven't learnt angular yet, but I'm about to, as I started to learn about node.js. Is this easily achieved with angular?

Comment: @ipid I updated the snippet to handle click events with jquery. It might be a good idea to move the button outside of the template so the click event doesn't need to be re-bound. Angular makes this easier by handling the changes for you, no re-rendering or re-binding.